# How to get rid off annoying android pop ups

Tags: ads, popup

Purchased LG Stylus 2 Plus 10 days back. Have got frustated with annoying pop up ads by android. Have started hating Google Play store due to these ads..

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways you can block ads:

For NON-ROOTED devices: Download APK Editor from the Play Store(Pro version lets you do more). You can use apk editor to remove ad strings and more.

For ROOTED devices: If your device is rooted, you can use an app called "Adaway". This app modifies a file in your system which is known as the "hosts" file.

With root, you are more likely to block all the ads.

I hope this helps!